# Как Дописывать данные в PHP сессию на каждой новой странице

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Помогите. Как правильно дописывать, добавлять новые данные к существующим в сессию PHP?
У меня на последующей странице записываются новые данные, но старые удаляются. А мне нужно их переносить и дописывать новые на каждой странице. Элементарно запутался.
Скриншоты приложил логики.

P.S: Ну или другой способ на PHP? чтобы на последней странице можно эти данные собрать в GET запрос отправить.

Скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код 1 страницы

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    
    session_start();
    // session_destroy(); //разрушить сессию
    
    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $_REQUEST['surname'];
    // $_SESSION['product1'] = $_REQUEST['product1'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
?>

<br><h1>СТРАНИЦА 1</h1></br>

<form action="" metod="GET">
    <input name="name">
    <input name="surname">
    <input type="submit" name='submit'>
</form>

<br>

<p><a href="index2.php" target="blank"><strong>Страница 2</strong></a></p><br>
<p><a href="index3.php" target="blank"><strong>Страница 3</strong></a></p><br>
```

Код 2 страницы

```
<?php
    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    
    session_start();
    
    if (isset($_REQUEST['product1'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $_REQUEST['surname'];
    $_SESSION['product1'] = $_REQUEST['product1'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    }

?>

<html>

<br><h1>СТРАНИЦА 2</h1></br>

</br>

<form method="GET">
<!-- Кнопка 1 с переменной: name="submit_ok" -->
<div class="cart_btn">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="product1" value="Кнопка 1" style="font-size:16px;"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


<!-- Кнопка 2 -->
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Нет, спасибо" style="font-size:16px;"/>
</div>
   
</form>



</html>
```

Код 3 страницы

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    
    session_start();
    
    if (isset($_REQUEST['product2'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $_REQUEST['surname'];
    $_SESSION['product1'] = $_REQUEST['product1'];
    $_SESSION['product2'] = $_REQUEST['product2'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
    
    




?>

<html>

<br><h1>СТРАНИЦА 3</h1></br>

</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<form method="GET">
<!-- Кнопка 1 с переменной: name="submit_ok" -->
<div class="cart_btn">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="product2" value="Кнопка 2" style="font-size:16px;"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


<!-- Кнопка 2 -->
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Нет, спасибо" style="font-size:16px;"/>
</div>
   
</form>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите со второй и третьей страниц строки:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
$_SESSION['surname'] = $_REQUEST['surname'];
```

А с третьей уберите

```
$_SESSION['product1'] = $_REQUEST['product1'];
```

Там эти данные у вас не отправляются в форме, поэтому вы просто перетираете их пустыми значениями

Comment: Спасибо большое.  Мне помогло это!
Подскажите, а как удалить конкретную запись данных. Например при посещении конкретной страницы или отправки GET: Имя или Фамилию или Запись. Только одно какое-то значение.

Comment: Если речь о сессии, то например так: unset($_SESSION['product1']);